# ASP.NET search application variables whose name starts with "xxx"

Tags: asp.net, variables, search, web-applications

I'mcreating a turn game ASP.NET based site where some players can start a game and other will simply join that game.

In order to manage each game I will create an application level variable with a set prefix, say "game_". And each game will bear a random game ID.

So there will be a bunch of variables like game_1234, game_56789, game_nnnn...

Question is: how can I retrieve all the **game_*** variables to look into their content and perform changes / remove some of them?

Edit: variables are stored with this code where gameID has been set at random:

```
HttpContext.Current.Application("game_" & gameID) = some_value
```

Comment: Sorry, but I have absolutely no idea what on earth you are asking. You're asking us how to check something, and not even told us how the information is stored. Quite simply not clear enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking how you can query and manipulate values in the `HttpContext.Current.Application` HttpApplicationState, you could do something like this:

```
foreach (var gameKey in HttpContext.Current.Application.AllKeys.Where(k => k.StartsWith("game_")
{
    var gameObject = HttpContext.Current.Application.Get(gameKey);

    //Do some work on gameObject
}
```

However, I would advise against keeping the data in `HttpContext.Current.Application`. If your app pool recycles it will be lost and if you ever want to add another server you will run into problems.  If this is more than a prototype, you might want to try a tool like [redis](http://redis.io).

Additionally, it would be nice to abstract this out a bit perhaps like:

public static class GameSessionService
    {
        private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary _games = 
            new ConcurrentDictionary();

```
    public static string CreateNewGame()
    {
        var gameId = "Game_" + Guid.NewGuid();

        var newGame = new object();

        _games.AddOrUpdate(gameId, k => newGame, (k,v) => newGame);

        return gameId;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<object> GetAllGames()
    {
        return _games.Values;
    }
}
```